# parametro a vista Django

Tags: django

Soy nuevo de Django. Estoy tratando de pasar un parámetro a una vista, para que me ponga el valor de identificación de forma predeterminada, y no toque volver a ingresarlo en el formulario pero me sale un error:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

si alguien me puede ayudar le agradezco mucho.

Adjunto código

```
models.py

class Ingreso_peatonal(models.Model):
    identificacion = models.ForeignKey(Visitante,verbose_name='Visitante',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipoingreso = models.ForeignKey(TipoIngreso,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vigilante =  models.CharField(max_length=15,verbose_name='Vigilante')
    hora_ingreso = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    hora_salida = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,editable=False)
    interior = models.ForeignKey(Interior,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    apartamento = models.ForeignKey(Apartamento,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering=["hora_ingreso"]
        verbose_name='Ingreso Peatonal'
        verbose_name_plural='Ingresos Peatonales'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.identificacion
```

```
forms.py

class IngresoPeatonalFormP(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingreso_peatonal
        fields = ['tipoingreso','interior','apartamento']
```

```
views.py

def IngresoPeatonalViewP(request,cc):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = IngresoPeatonalFormP(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pp = form.save(commit=False)
            context=['Ingreso_peatonal']
            context['identificacion'] = cc
            pp.vigilante = request.user
            pp.save()
            success_url = reverse_lazy('ingreso_peatonal')
     else:
        form = IngresoPeatonalFormP()
        return render(request, 'core/ingreso_peatonal_p.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada un error que veo es que estas manipulando una lista como un diccionario:

```
context=['Ingreso_peatonal']
context['identificacion'] = cc
```

Estas declarando una lista y después agregas una `key` y un `value` a una lista, aunque no la estas agregando pues no es un diccionario, creo que a eso se debe el error.

Otro punto es que estas poniendo un objeto (`self.request.user`), al campo `vigilante` y por lo que puedo ver en tu modelo el campo `vigilante` es de tipo `CharField`, por lo cual daría error, tendría que ser el campo un relación para así funcionar, aunque no estoy seguro si dará o no error capas si funciona pues puede dar el resultado del metodo `__str__`, nunca lo he intentado.

También puedo observar que en tu vista no estas redireccionando a ningún lugar en especifico, cuando se rellene el formulario, te hago caer en cuenta por se acaso te ayas olvidado.